# Command button and run/sub user form button not in sync

Tags: vba, excel

on my excel sheet, I have a command button (GrabMyData) which grabs, copies data onto a workbook (thisWB). Now when I press this command button, the data appears on the 'top rows' of the column. However, on the excel VBA editor, when I press the run/sub userform play button, the data comes to the 'last rows' of data on the column, which is what I want. So, why is my command button not doing what the run/sub play button is doing? I thought they both do the same function. Please note, I have correctly assigned the macro command button to the relevant work book. Please advise.

```
Sub GrabMyData()
  Dim myWB As Workbook
  Dim thisWB As Workbook
  Dim thisWS As Worksheet
  Dim lastRow As String

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Set myWB =  Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\jjordan\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.Outlook\GTER232\TEST.csv")

  myWB.Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A8:F17").Copy

  Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
  Set thisWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 5")

  thisWB.Activate

  lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

  thisWS.Range("H" & lastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
With Application
    .CutCopyMode = False
    .ScreenUpdating = True
  End With

 myWB.Close


End Sub
```

Comment: So the destination is different, right?  Looks like in the code the destination is computed as `lastRow`, right?  Can you try using a debug print on the value, so `Debug.Print lastRow`?  Also do you need to use ActiveSheet, I'd pin that sucker down with a name so `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("foo")`.

Comment: Yes the destination is different. Yes, its is computed as the lastRow, as I want the imported data to appear at the last row within the column range and not at the top rows in the column range. So, I presume the run/sub user button in the vba editor, even though it does what I want the code is still wrong if the macro button does something different? I will make the changes you suggested and see what happens.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still getting the same results.

Comment: Swap thisWS for ActiveSheet.

Comment: @S Meaden, Thank you! It works now. So, it was a small tweak that did it. But one needs the experience to know where to look. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing **thisworkbook** to **workbooks("workbook name")**?